# Number of participants with observations

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset and I am trying to obtain the number of observations for each participant (e.g., how many participants have repeated observations across the 13 timepoints, some may have 13, whereas others may only have 1, 2, 3, 4 observations etc).

My data is in wide format, variables are 1D, the 13 timepoints (i.e., birth to 15.5years), and first I will group by `Autism` (so I only see those with `ASD` and not `NoASD`, although have just realised, that the Autism column may be long format as I have `ASD` and `NoASD` in same column) .

This is the code I have tried:

```r
nrow(df[df$"Birth", "4m", "8m", "12m", "1.5y", "2y", "2.5y", "3y", "3.5y", "4y", "5y", "7y", "15.5y" & df$"ID" & df$Autism == "ASD", ])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Sarah, could you share an example of your data with `dput(df)` to handle your question?

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting data is indeed an easy way to count available observations:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~Birth, ~`4m`, ~`8m`, ~`12m`, ~Autism,
  1, 1, 2, NA, 1, TRUE,
  2, 2, 1, 2, 2, FALSE,
  3, 2, 3, NA, NA, FALSE,
)

counts <-
  data %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?[my]")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(Autism, Birth, ID) %>%
  summarise(n_observations = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Autism', 'Birth'. You can override using
#> the `.groups` argument.
counts
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Autism Birth    ID n_observations
#>   <lgl>  <dbl> <dbl>          <int>
#> 1 FALSE      2     2              3
#> 2 FALSE      2     3              1
#> 3 TRUE       1     1              2

counts %>%
  count(Autism, n_observations, name = "n_patients")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Autism n_observations n_patients
#>   <lgl>           <int>      <int>
#> 1 FALSE               1          1
#> 2 FALSE               3          1
#> 3 TRUE                2          1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

There is only one non autistic patient having all 3 observations (in this example).

Comment: Thank you @Danlooo for your answer, im quite new to R and would really appreciate if you could give an explanation to the code? e.g., would you be able to explain what the 1, 1, 2, NA, 1 TRUE etc comes from please?  and also why you chose pivet 0-9? Im unsure how to fit this to my data

Comment: I needed to create my own example. I assumed Autism to be logical (e.g. FALSE == "NoASD"). `"^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?[my]"` is a regular expression to select columns (start with a number and contains either m or y). `pivot_longer` is to have one row per observation time point. You count rows, so you want to have one obs per row.